# c# winform listbox adds system.collection to listbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dictionary, listbox

to whom it may respond to , 
we have 2 listboxes that use dictionaries as datasource. The code to swap element between textboxes is as :

```
private void btnSrc2Trg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lbxSourceSite.Items.Count > 0 ) {
        try { 
            string[] item = lbxSourceSite.Items[lbxSourceSite.SelectedIndex].ToString().Replace("[","").Split(',');
            dctTargetsites.Add(item[0], item[1]);
            dctSites.Remove(item[0]);
            lbxSourceSite.DataSource = null;
            lbxSourceSite.DataSource = new BindingSource(dctSites,null);
            lbxSourceSite.DisplayMember = "Key";
            lbxSourceSite.ValueMember = "Value";
            lbxTargetSite.DataSource = null;
            lbxTargetSite.DataSource =  new BindingSource(dctTargetsites, null);
            lbxTargetSite.DisplayMember = "Key";
            lbxTargetSite.ValueMember = "Value";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.GetBaseException().Message.ToString());
        }
    }

}

private void btnTrg2Src_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lbxTargetSite.Items.Count > 0 ) {
        try{
            string[] item = lbxTargetSite.Items[lbxTargetSite.SelectedIndex].ToString().Replace("[", "").Split(',');
            dctSites.Add(item[0], item[1]);
            dctTargetsites.Remove(item[0]);

            lbxTargetSite.DataSource = null;
            lbxTargetSite.DataSource = new BindingSource(dctTargetsites, null);
            lbxTargetSite.DisplayMember = "Key";
            lbxTargetSite.ValueMember = "Value";

            lbxSourceSite.DataSource = null;
            lbxSourceSite.DataSource = new BindingSource(dctSites, null);
            lbxSourceSite.DisplayMember = "Key";
            lbxSourceSite.ValueMember = "Value";
        }catch(Exception ex){
            MessageBox.Show(ex.GetBaseException().Message.ToString());              
        }
    }
}
```

After adding the last element to target textbox and removing from source textbox (or vice versa) , there an element as displayed as  "system.collection" , it might be related to re-binding dictionaries as datasources after operation, how can I get rid of it?
Or any other proper method to use dictionaries for listbox is welcomed, 
Thank you for your concern

Comment: do you need the values of the dictionary as items in the listbox?

Comment: hi csharper, thanks for response, I am planning to use the target dictionary as an input to some other function , but I am open for any alternatives

Answer (score 0):

The displayed element "system.collection" may occur becaus you are using

```
string[] item = lbxSourceSite.Items[lbxSourceSite.SelectedIndex].ToString().Replace("[","").Split(',');
```

the `ToString()` method will return you the name of the data type of the selected item -> system.collection.

You could use:

```
string[] item = lbxSourceSite.Items[lbxSourceSite.SelectedIndex].Text.Replace("[","").Split(',');
```

or even:

```
string[] item = lbxSourceSite.Items[lbxSourceSite.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString().Replace("[","").Split(',');
```

You have to change this in both listboxes :)

Comment: hi toby, thanks for response but .text or .value doesnt seem to be properties of this , 4 methods occur only : tostring , equals, gethashcode and gettype

Comment: um... okay well :D sorry then. maybe the msdn [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx) may help you.

Comment: np :) mein deutsch is nicht sehr gut aber vielen dank. :)